# Java Manifest error

Tags: java, arduino, manifest

I'd like to test arduino-uno 3G communication.
It's able to http or FTP connection.

Fortunately, I founded java application at the web site.

http://m2msupport.net/m2msupport/module-tester/

I connected PC with arduino(assembled 3G shield) and execute application

However,I couldn't solve that java manifest error

This is capture of java consol.

```
Missing Permissions manifest attribute in main jar:htt p://www.m2msupport.net/m2msupport/wp-content/themes/admired/ATCommandTester_v27.jar
```

So,I downloaded `ATCommandTester_v27.jar` and 
checked `/META-INF/MANIFEST.MF` file

manifest file contents are very long

```
Manifest-Version: 1.0
Name: ATCommandTester_v27$16.class
SHA1-Digest: IAVLk9iLe0xidNObckHpnRh0P/w=
Name: ATCommandTester_v27$1$4.class
SHA1-Digest: iEG0DitzECDEIT+as8n2+DCkrKY=.....
```

I'm already done this command `jarsigner -verify ATCommandTester_v27.jar`
but, I still blocked
[screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/iEcdQ.jpg)

What have I got to do?
Thanks for your help!

Comment: Err, add the missing Permissions manifest attribute? Have you considered looking it up?